# Python - Am I able to pass an APScheduler as a parameter?

Tags: python, parameter-passing, scheduler, apscheduler

This code for example:

```
def main():

    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()

    refresh(scheduler)  # refresh will add a job to the scheduler

    while True:
        refresh(scheduler)
        sleep(10)
        continue


def refresh(scheduler):
    rundate = datetime.datetime.now()
    rundate = rundate + datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)
    scheduler.add_job(job_function, run_date=rundate)


def job_function():
    print("Hello, World!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

After running it, "Hello, World!" will never print. Is it possible to pass a BackgroundScheduler() object and add to it within that function? Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: @SamCraig I'm passing it to the scheduler, with the `run_date` set to 10 seconds in the future for the scheduler to invoke the function at that time. Or at least that's how I thought APScheduler works?